# Populating a Google Chart with a MongoDB Projection using AJAX/Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, mongodb, google-visualization

I just got done with the MongoDB [tutorial for nodejs](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M101JS/about) on its website, and am trying to construct a very simple test case for sending the results of a query to a Google Chart via AJAX.

Here is the nodejs file I'm using to generate the query:

**CODE:**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
assert      = require('assert');

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/crunchbase', function(err, db) {
assert.equal(err, null);
console.log('The app is now running');

var query      = {name:  { $regex: /^m/}, founded_year: { $gte: 2009 }};
var projection = {name: 1, founded_year: 1, _id: 0};
var cursor     = db.collection('companies').find(query);
cursor.project(projection);
});
```

The example I'm using to load the cursor into a google chart [comes from this page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example).

Here's my sample code that I'm using to generate the chart:

**CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!--Load the AJAX API for Google Charts- -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:27017/crunchbase",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        asynchronous: true
    }).responseText;

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
    var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById("chartDiv"));
    chart.draw(data);

  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="text-align: center">Companies Starting With "M" Founded After 2009</h1>
<div id="chartDiv">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I currently get this error message in the console:

**ERROR MESSGE:**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier    crunchbase?callback=jQuery1102076…_1481945533315&_=1481945533316:1
```

**Also of note:**  I changed `dataType` to `jsonp` and `asynchronous` to `true` in order to get error messages to go away, but these run counter to the example given by the Google Charts example so this might be relevant.

I apologize if my code is a bit crude, this is really just trying to tack together very basic examples from both the MongoDB and Google Charts documentation and get them to work.

Answer (score 1):

when `asynchronous: true` --> need to wait for the request to finish,
before trying to use the data / draw the chart

see `.done` -- try following snippet...

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:27017/crunchbase",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    asynchronous: true
  }).done(function (jsonData) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
    var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById("chartDiv"));
    chart.draw(data);
  }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
    console.log(errorMessage);
  });
}
```

Comment: hope this helps -- fyi: if you want to create the google data table directly from json, it needs to match the [format found here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)...